# shogun toolbox Error: Makefile:527: recipe for target `libshogun-12.0.dll' failed using Cygwin

Tags: matlab, compilation, machine-learning, cygwin, shogun

I'm trying to install shogun library for SVM and I'm using the latest version of Cygwin on windows vista which has swig 2.0.8, usually the "./configure --interfaces=matlab_static" command goes smoothly, whenever I type "make" I get the error message Makefile:527: recipe for target `libshogun-12.0.dll' failed using Cygwin, and as a result I don't get the "sg.dll" that should be generated after the make command which I'll use to run matlab interface on shogun.

any suggestions or help are really appreciated
thanks

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the shogun developers aren't too bothered about supporting windows, so I would just suggest you try this on a linux (virtual) machine.

You should definitely send this question to the shogun mailing list, though, to get a definitive answer. Details on how to sign up for the list are on [their contact page](http://shogun-toolbox.org/page/contact/contacts).